# Same value in list keeps getting repeated when writing to text file

Tags: python, python-2.7, text-files

I'm a total noob to Python and need some help with my code.
The code is meant to take Input.txt [http://pastebin.com/bMdjrqFE], split it into seperate Pokemon (in a list), and then split that into seperate values which I use to reformat the data and write it to Output.txt.

However, when I run the program, only the last Pokemon gets outputted, 386 times. [http://pastebin.com/wkHzvvgE]

Here's my code:

```
f = open("Input.txt", "r")#opens the file (input.txt)
nf = open("Output.txt", "w")#opens the file (output.txt)
pokeData = []
for line in f:
    #print "%r" % line
    pokeData.append(line)
num = 0
tab = """   """
newl = """NEWL
"""
slash = "/"
while num != 386:
    current = pokeData
    current.append(line)
    print current[num]
    for tab in current:
        words = tab.split()
        print words
    for newl in words:
        nf.write('%s:{num:%s,species:"%s",types:["%s","%s"],baseStats:{hp:%s,atk:%s,def:%s,spa:%s,spd:%s,spe:%s},abilities:{0:"%s"},{1:"%s"},heightm:%s,weightkg:%s,color:"Who cares",eggGroups:["%s"],["%s"]},\n' % (str(words[2]).lower(),str(words[1]),str(words[2]),str(words[3]),str(words[4]),str(words[5]),str(words[6]),str(words[7]),str(words[8]),str(words[9]),str(words[10]),str(words[12]).replace("_"," "),str(words[12]),str(words[14]),str(words[15]),str(words[16]),str(words[16])))
    num = num + 1
nf.close()
f.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few problems with your program starting with the file reading.
To read the lines of a file to an array you can use file.readlines().

So instead of

```
f = open("Input.txt", "r")#opens the file (input.txt)
pokeData = []
for line in f:
     #print "%r" % line
     pokeData.append(line)
```

You can just do this

```
pokeData = open("Input.txt", "r").readlines() # This will return each line within an array.
```

Next you are misunderstanding the uses of `for` and `while`.

A `for` loop in python is designed to iterate through an array or list as shown below. I don't know what you were trying to do by `for newl in words`, a for loop will create a new variable and then iterate through an array setting the value of this new variable. Refer below.

```
array = ["one", "two", "three"]
for i in array: # i is created
    print (i)
```

The output will be:

```
one
two
three
```

So to fix alot of this code you can replace the whole while loop with something like this.

(The code below is assuming your input file has been formatted such that all the words are split by tabs)

```
for line in pokeData:
    words = line.split (tab) # Split the line by tabs
    nf.write ('your very long and complicated string')
```

## Other helpers

The formatted string that you write to the output file looks very similar to the `JSON` format. There is a builtin python module called `json` that can convert a native python `dict` type to a json string. This will probably make things alot easier for you but either way works.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was able to figure it out thanks to you.